# Adding custom line to ggplot throws error: Aesthetics must be length 1

Tags: r, ggplot2, nlp

Trying to colour over a portion of a line in ggplot. This colour represents meaningful words in word frequency rankings filtered from the original plotted data.

Error:

> Error in `check_aesthetics()`: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or
> the same as the data (1306062): x and y

Original plot:

```
#plot
word_freq_rank <- ggplot(word_list, aes(x = seq_along(freqs), y = freqs, group = 1)) + 
        geom_line() +
        coord_trans(y ='log10', x='log10') +
        labs(title = "Rank Frequency Plot", x = "log-Rank", y = "log-Frequency")
```

Text processing:

```
# REMOVE STOPWORDS AND INFREQUENT WORDS- TO DEFINE BEST RANGE FOR ANALYSIS, by removing insignificant word indexes

stopword_idx <- which(word_list$words %in% stop_words)
low_frequent_idx <- which(word_list$freqs < 10)
insignificant_idx <- union(stopword_idx, low_frequent_idx)
meaningful_range_idx <- setdiff(1:nrow(word_list), insignificant_idx)
```

Adding line:

```
# plot the meaningful range of the rank-frequency to use
word_freq_rank +  geom_path(mapping = aes(x = meaningful_range_idx, y = freqs[meaningful_range_idx], color="green"), inherit.aes = TRUE)
```

The error happens when I try to add the line at end of code below. I'm missing something basic but at a loss. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can't reproduce without data, but you might want to try making a data.frame to pass to `geom_path`. Also, move `color="green"` to outside the `aes`.

Comment: Maybe set `inherit.aes = FALSE` in the `geom_path` layer? Seems like you are specifying all the aesthetics you need.